# <li> not totally colored

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a list with some elements. Simple list. I've coded a hover property on `<li>` tag to change his background colour to white. Simple behaviour.
My problem is: the height doesn't filled totally.
I've tried to reset margin and padding `li{padding:0; margin:0;}` but didn't work too.

This is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ctvalex/jh3t5t1b/2/

Any help is welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Just Change the display styling for

```
#bottom-menu ul li
```

to

```
display: inline-block;
```

so it'll be like that

```
#bottom-menu ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   line-height: 50px;
}
```

Check the Edited Example http://jsfiddle.net/jh3t5t1b/6/